# Unsupported protocol: rest mobilefirst

Tags: rest, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to setup my first mobile app but without success for more than a week now

I use MFP 7.0 and MySQL 56 on RHEL 6.  I am still trying to find a solution for this error through google

I use 'localConnector-1.0' in server.xml as shown below

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>

    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
```

But in messages.log I am able to see 'connection via REST' despite using 'localConnector' followed by 'Malformed URL'

```
[7/31/15 9:57:35:188 IST] 00000048 com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyRuntimeMBeanHandler     I Establishing REST connection to service:jmx:rest://localhost:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST
[7/31/15 9:57:35:189 IST] 00000048 com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyRuntimeMBeanHandler     I Establishing REST connection to service:jmx:rest://localhost:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST

[7/31/15 9:57:35:190 IST] 00000048 com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean            E FWLSE0320E: Failed to check whether the admin services are ready. Caused by: [project worklightconsole]
java.net.MalformedURLException: Unsupported protocol: rest
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.newJMXConnector(JMXConnectorFactory.java:367)
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:277)    
        at com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyRuntimeMBeanHandler.getMBeanServerConnection(LibertyRuntimeMBeanHandler.java:84)
        at com.worklight.common.util.jmx.MBeanConnectorFactory.getLocalMBeanProxy(MBeanConnectorFactory.java:139)
        at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean.isReady(ProjectSynchronizationBean.java:126)
        at com.worklight.core.init.WorklightServletInitializer$1.run(WorklightServletInitializer.java:140)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
```

Any help or URL links will be of great help

Answer (score 1):

By design, the connection to the MobileFirst Admin Services uses JMX and is secured with SSL.
To make it possible to use such a connection, you have to use feature restConnector-1.0 in Liberty instead of feature localConnector-1.0.

"Configuring secure JMX connection to the Liberty profile"
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_admin_restconnector.html?cp=SSD28V_8.5.5%2F1-5-2-10-1

This is mentioned in the MobileFirst 7.0 documentation in section "Configuring WebSphere Application Server Liberty profile"
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_optional_config_app_server_liberty.html
where it is said that MobileFirst Server requires the secure JMX connection to be configured.

You may find the manual steps for configuring the MobileFirst Admin Services in this section
"Configuring WebSphere Application Server Liberty profile for MobileFirst Server administration manually"
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_liberty_profile_for_wladmin_manually.html

The list of Liberty features to use depends on Liberty version but in all cases, you can notice that only feature restConnector-1.0 is used.

To go a step further, note that there is also a section for configuring Liberty with MySQL
"Configuring Liberty profile for MySQL manually"
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_configuring_liberty_profile_for_my_sql_manually.html